# Writing data to text file using write() in R in specific layout

Tags: r

I have a number of data values that are printed to the R console (in no particular format, such as a matrix or dataframe). To export to a file, I am using write() with the append = TRUE argument.

To write data to the file via write(), the argument sep = "\n" can be used to write each value on a new line.

Is there a clean way to ensure the following layout within the text file using the 'sep' argument?

```
a
b
c

d
e
f
```

that is, place a single blank space after every third (or whatever is wanted) value? Above a-f represent numeric values.

Comment: As always, it depends. What does your input data look like? Does using `sep="\n"` suffice?

Comment: @r2evans sep = "\n" puts each appended value on a separate line (this was mentioned in my post), which is what I am looking for (it suffices partially). However, in order to make the text output more aesthetic, I would like a blank white space to be placed after every third value. My input are simply numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a vector, I'll use `letters`:

```
nth <- 3
write(
  paste(
    sapply(split(letters, cumsum(seq_along(letters) %% nth == 1)),
           paste, collapse = "\n"),
    collapse = "\n\n"
  ),
  file = "quux.txt"
)
```